# Autocovariance of a Random Walk Proof

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, random-walk

I'm currently looking at these notes online to try to understand the proof of the auto-covariance of a random walk (Slides 19 and 29 specifically)
http://www.personal.psu.edu/asb17/old/sta4853/files/sta4853-2.pdf

Given a random walk we know at time $t$ the random process $Z_t = \delta t +\sum_{j=1}^{t} a_{j}$.

We know that the autocovariance is:
$$\gamma(s,t) = Cov(Z_s,Z_t) = Cov(\sum_{j=1}^{s} a_{j},\sum_{j=1}^{t} a_{k})$$
$$= \sum_{j=1}^{s}\sum_{j=1}^{t} cov(a_j,a_k)$$
$$ = min(s,t) $$

I'm confused about the last line. Why does the summation equal to the minimum of s and t?

Comment: The $a_j$ are iid, so $\text{Cov}(a_j,a_k)=0$ unless $j=k$, and so on.

Comment: Why does that mean the summation is equal to the $min(s,t)$?

Answer (score 1):

You're told at the top of slide $29$ that $\ a_t\sim\ \text{WN}(0, \sigma^2)\ $, so $\ Cov\left(a_j,a_k\right)=\sigma^2\delta_{jk}\ $. Therefore
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^s\sum_{k=1}^t Cov\left(a_j,a_k\right)
&=\sigma^2\sum_{j=1}^s\sum_{k=1}^t \delta_{jk}\\
 &= \sigma^2\sum_{j=1}^s\mathbb{1}_{\{j\le t\}}\\
&= \sigma^2\min(s,t)
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain what $$\sigma^2\sum_{j=1}^s\mathbb{1}_{\{j\le t\}}$$ means? I'm unfamiliar with some of the notation and how you move from the prior step to this one.

Comment: $$\mathbb{1}_{\{j\le t\}}=\cases{0& if $j>t\ ,$\\1& if$j\le t\ $.}$$ This is the value of the inner sum because if $\ j>t\ $ then $\ \delta_{jk}=0\ $ for all $\ k\ $ in the range from $1$ to $\ t\ $, whereas if $\ j\le t\ $ then $\ \delta_{jj}=1\ $, but $\ \delta_{jk}=0\ $ for all other $\ k\ $ in the range from $1$ to $\ t\ $.